# Using TabViewController, When saving data, TableView not updating

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My current setup: TabViewController that is connected to two TableViewControllers embedded in navigation controllers. I am able to update the tableview no problem, on app load and when switching back between the different tabs.
My problem comes when I open another tableviewcontroller to edit. When I hit save from this view controller, it updates the data and saves everything just fine however, My tableView will not update no matter what I try unless I switch between the different tabs or close and reopen the app.

I have tried using delegates to trigger the update, I have tried use NSNotificationCenter, and no dice.

Has anybody else had this issue?

Here is my save function:

```swift
    func saveDose(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
        if searchName == "" {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
        let dose = Dose(context: managedContext)

        let doseNumberString = numberDosesText.text
        let doseNumberInt = Int64(doseNumberString!) ?? 0

        dose.name = nameText.text

        dose.script = scriptText.text
        dose.dosage = dosageText.text
        //        dose.doseInterval = doseInterval
        dose.firstDose = datePicker.date
        dose.numberDoses = doseNumberInt

        dose.doseReminder = remindersSwitch.isOn

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            print("Data Saved")
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save data: ", error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }
        } else {
            update(name:searchName, firstDose: searchDate)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
```

And here is where I call it and load back to my other tableview.

```swift
    @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        saveDose { (done) in
            if done {
                print("We need to return now")
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("Try again")
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is where I reload my tableview when the view appears

```swift
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("View has been loaded back from other view")
            self.fetchData()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("View will appear")
    }
```

And here is my fetchData and loadData functions

```swift
  func fetchData() {
        loadData { (done) in
            if done {
                setEmptyView(Array: logArray.count)
            }
        }
    }


    func loadData(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
        guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Log")
        do {
            logArray = try managedContext.fetch(request) as! [Log]
            print("Data Fetched No Issues")
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch data: ", error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

Again I have tried delegates and have used this code in other applications that have worked fine. Is it something to do with the tab bar controller?

The data is obviously saving fine, I just can't get the tableView to update properly.

It seems like it is not calling the viewWillAppear function after the save. I have tried using delegates as well to force the update of the tableview but nothing has been working.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Are you calling tableView.reloadData() after you modified the tableview data source?

Comment: show your code bro ...

Comment: Yes I do call tableView.reloadData(). I believe that after I pop the navigation controller, my original tableviewcontroller is not calling viewwillappear where I call for the updates. Even I if I call it using a delegate it won't reload my data. Is this a problem with my TabBarController possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to call tableView.reloadData(). after you have done saving. 
Moreover you can use `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates` on tableView to perform animations on specific rows. for more information on this you may refer to [This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Comment: On iOS 13 it is recommended to use the new `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`instead of the beginUpdates() and endUpdates() workaround for animations.

Answer (score 0):

Reload your tableview in custom delegates method your problem will be solved.